# The ajax data is not sending on update jQuery sortable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

There is this piece of javascript/jQuery code that uses the sortable feature of jQuery. I use it to sort an unknown amount of divs, although currently I'm trying to send the data to the database with ajax:

Javascript with jQuery.sortable & ajax

```
var lst, pre;

$(".sortlist").sortable({
    start:function(event, ui){
        pre = ui.item.index();
    },
    axis: 'y',
    handle: '.handle',
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var data = $("#list1").sortable("toArray");

        console.log($("#list1").serializeArray = data);

        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'backend/components/reorder-cards.php'
        });
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        lst = $(this).attr('id');
        post = ui.item.index();
        other = (lst == 'list1') ? 'list2' : 'list1';
        //Use insertBefore if moving UP, or insertAfter if moving DOWN
        if (post > pre) {
            $('#'+other+ ' div:eq(' +pre+ ')').insertAfter('#'+other+ ' div:eq(' +post+ ')');
        } else {
            $('#'+other+ ' div:eq(' +pre+ ')').insertBefore('#'+other+ ' div:eq(' +post+ ')');
        }
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Every update it should use the code to do an `INSERT` in the php file called reorder-cards.php:

```
include('../../config/connect.php');
$data = $_POST['include('../../config/connect.php');
$data = $_POST['data'];

$insertdata = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO pageOrder (order) VALUES (:order)");
$insertdata->bindParam(':order', $data, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insertdata->execute();'];

$insertdata = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO pageOrder (order) VALUES (:order)");
$insertdata->bindParam(':order', $data, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insertdata->execute();
```

However it's not sending anything to the database, I've never gotten an insert via ajax to work. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the DevTools (for example in Chrome) to check if you send an correct Ajax request, so it's easier to locate your problem.

Comment: There are no errors in console, that is the reason I do not get what I did wrong...

Comment: Alright I take that back, I added the succes function of ajax and now I see the php errors in console